# Can something be named without the use of a proper noun or equivalent?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

We are told in mathematics that they can be named using symbols and number words that act as proper nouns in english.

However, we use 'two' and '2' in strange ways, for example we say 'two things' or 'two' men or 'two apples' and in this case 'two' refers to a number but not as a proper noun in language.

The same is for ideas like 'green', 'green' is a colour, but we can have a 'green car'.

Can we name by description, for example, '2 metres' is both a description of a length and also used as a proper noun 'name' for it, for example '2 metres is a length'.

Is it a case that 'mathematical language' treets 'symbols' and words as proper nouns, whereas natural language does not?

We can identify a word like 'green' or 'two' without it as the noun, is this still a 'name'?

Comment: See [Definite descrption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description).

Comment: "green" is the name of a *property*. Regarding numbers, there is an enduring discussion: number words are names of objects or names of properties? See e.g. Frege's [The Foundations of Arithmetic (1884)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Foundations_of_Arithmetic), still the best philosophical book about numbers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA that is a great source, it explores what I am wondering about exactly.